# Looking up values from different tables including newly found values

Tags: excel

I have several documents which contain statistical data of performance of companies. There are about 60 different excel sheets representing different months and I want to collect data into one big table. Original tables looks something like this, but are bigger:

[image]

Each company takes two rows which represent their profit from the sales of the product and cost to manufacture the product.I need both of these numbers.

As I said, there are ~60 these tables and I want to extract information about Product2. I want to put everything into one table where columns would represent months and rows - profit and costs of each company. It could be easily done (I think) with INDEX function as all sheets are named similarly. The problem I faced is that at some periods of time other companies enter the market:
[image]

Some of them stay, some of them fail. I would like to collect information on all companies that exist today or ever existed, but newly found companies distort the list (in second picture we see, that company BA is in 4th row, not BB). As row of a company changes from time to time, using INDEX becomes problematic, because in some cases results of different companies get into one row. Adjusting them one by one seems very painful.

Maybe there is some quick and efficient method to solve such problem?

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One think you may want to try is linking the Excel spreadsheets as tables in Access.  From there you can create a query that ties the tables together.  As data changes in the spreadsheets, the query will reflect those changes.